# Load certificate in code from function app service

Tags: .net, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-functions

I have a .pfx file imported in the SSL settings of my azure function app like so:

[image]

And I have set WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES to '*' in app settings which should mean that my app loads any certificate found.

[image]

And finally in my code I load and use the certificate like so:

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "13865DB1**************33384B053E4B5", true);

log.LogInformation("Number of certificates in collection: " + certCollection.Count.ToString());

certStore.Close();

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certCollection[0]);
```

When the function runs the log line says "Number of certificates in collection: 0", and the `handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certCollection[0]);` gives an index out of bounds exception. Is there anything wrong with how I use the certificate in my code or any reason why it would not get loaded? I assume it should happen automatically when WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES is '*'.

EDIT: It seems to be working when switching from `true` to `false` in 
`X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "13865DB1**************33384B053E4B5", true);`, but I don't understand why. The bool is called `validOnly` so I feel like `true` should be the correct value as the certificate I'm looking for is valid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at this [**`answer`**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e619fec3-a209-4981-a499-30f4b5d34135/x509certificate2collectionfind-what-is-a-valid-certificate?forum=clr),

If validOnly is set to true, the function calls X509Utils.VerifyCertificate which further calls the native API CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy to verify the certificate. The CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy function checks a certificate chain to verify its validity, including its compliance with any specified validity policy criteria.

Also, I would recommend you to add array.length method to check the number of certificates and access the first element.